# Azure Data factory split file into multiple files using column position

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a delimited file that contains the data of the following columns.

ID, Column 1, Column 2, Column 3

I want to split this file into two files with file-1 containing ID, Column 1, Column 2

And file-2 with columns ID, Column 3

I was able to do it in python using split function using the column position. Wondering if its possible to do the same in the Data factory.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create pipeline and add dataflow activity in it

[image]

Add Source data set as your blob storage csv file then by clicking `+` next to source create a new branch of source by selecting `new branch`

[image]

Source setting

[image]

by clicking `+` next to source create a select activity for source by selecting `select`. then it will show columns in your csv file delete the column you don't want (here I selected Column3). and click on delete.

[image]

Sink setting

[image]

Output two files with desired columns:

[image]